# Using C# - Can I have help changing this code so my appointment update shows 15min Appointment reminder alerts before each appointment for the day

Tags: c#, appointment

````
     // Check for upcoming appointments
       ``` foreach (DataRow row in dtblAppointments.Rows)
        {
            DateTime eventDT = 
    DateTime.Parse(row["Start"].ToString());

            if(eventDT > DateTime.Now && eventDT.AddMinutes(15) 
    >= DateTime.Now)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Alert - Appointment " + 
    row["ID"].ToString() + " " + row["Title"].ToString() + " 
    starts in 15 minutes or less.");
            }

        }```
````

Updated the code, i copied in the wrong lines. Can someone help me create an alert for a appointment that is occurring within 15 min. This just randomly alerts for the entire day

Comment: this code is nothing to do with alerts or 15 minutes. it is a function to delete an appointment

Comment: Can you include example data for "Start"?

Answer (score 0):

This will match only events occurring between now and 15 minutes from now. But it won't keep you from getting alerts multiple times within that period.

```
if (eventDT >= DateTime.Now && eventDT <= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15))
```

Comment: awesome thank you